# In Corda, `KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID` despite registering classes

Tags: corda

I have written an application that uses a Spring Boot webserver to speak to a Corda node.

I have whitelisted all the required classes, but when I start a flow on the node, I get the following exception:

```
[WARN ] 2018-05-31T01:52:17,723Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - Inbound RPC failed {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Book, L=Shanghai, C=CN, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=a1d3ad59-fb5c-4037-897e-a5c19d1d281e, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-31T01:52:17.723Z, session_id=9595bff5-3982-4a76-967a-85f2b88f5347, session_timestamp=2018-05-31T01:46:55.130Z}
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 109
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:804) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.DefaultKryoCustomizer$NonEmptySetSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:181) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.DefaultKryoCustomizer$NonEmptySetSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:169) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:97) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:80) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:94) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:570) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:79) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:196) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:79) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServerKt$sam$MessageHandler$5b9bfc45.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a classpath conflict. Corda 3.1 uses Guava 21.0, whereas the CorDapp in question was using Guava 22.0.

After downgrading the version of Guava used by the CorDapp to Guava 21.0, this issue was resolved.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in Flink, what should I do here?