# Using Corda RPC API in Spring Boot throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, corda

I have a multimodule project similar to [this one](https://github.com/lankydan/spring-webflux-and-corda).

I'm using Corda 3.2, Spring Boot 2 without Kotlin and I have a set of Corda nodes running thanks to cordformation. I'm able to connect successfully to a node from my Spring Boot app, but getting into to trouble when trying to, for example, get nodeInfo.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578603/using-spring-boot-for-replacing-corda-server-giving-privacy-salt-should-be-32-bi). But the answer to "clear caches" there is confusing to me. Does it mean to clear gradle's cache? How would that help?

Here's my stack trace:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Privacy salt should be 32 bytes.
Serialization trace:
legalIdentitiesAndCerts (net.corda.core.node.NodeInfo)
value (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:97) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:80) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:94) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:360) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:256) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:197) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$MessageHandler$6fb61eb3.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1003) ~[artemis-core-client-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50) ~[artemis-core-client-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1126) ~[artemis-core-client-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Privacy salt should be 32 bytes.
    at net.corda.core.contracts.PrivacySalt.(Structures.kt:303) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.DefaultKryoCustomizer$PrivacySaltSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:197) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.DefaultKryoCustomizer$PrivacySaltSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:191) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

The privacy salt that needed to be 32 bytes long was 56 bytes for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Spring Boot For replacing Corda server giving privacy salt should be 32 bit exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578603/using-spring-boot-for-replacing-corda-server-giving-privacy-salt-should-be-32-bi)

Comment: I think the answer on that other question is a bit unhelpful, it should at least explain what happened and exactly how to solve this. Could you comment on that answer to get more information?

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I'll ask to expand the answer on the other question.

Comment: Edit: Unfortunately I have too little rep to add a comment there :( Could you help me out perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was not too new Gradle version.
It came from the fact that my Spring Boot app had Guava dependency with version 26.0, but Corda 3.2 has version 21.0.

Related Stackoverflow question regarding this is [In Corda, `KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID` despite registering classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639058/in-corda-kryoexception-encountered-unregistered-class-id-despite-registering)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Guava dependency version. I had version 27 and was facing this issue i changes version to 21 and it  works...

Using corda 3.3